# How do I grab multiple fields of a MySQL record from dropdown box of a child popup window to insert those values in multiple fields of parent page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this in the popup, which creates the dropdown with database entries.

```
<select name="ddlNames" id="ddlNames">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["vendorid"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["vendorname"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetVendor();" />
```

Then this javascript takes the values and inserts them into the fields of parent page and also closes the popup at the same time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetVendor() {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
        var vendor_name = window.opener.document.getElementById("vendor_name");
        var vendor_nameSelect = document.getElementById("ddlNames");
        var vendor_nameSelectedText = vendor_nameSelect.options[vendor_nameSelect.selectedIndex].text;
        vendor_name.value = vendor_nameSelectedText;

        var vendorid = window.opener.document.getElementById("vendorid");
        vendorid.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
    }
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

I am already grabbing 2 different fields.  an id number which are populated in the value parameter of each option, and the name of each option as well.

So now i want a third thing, then 4th and 5th and so on.  i can't just put this in the dropdown options loop.  doesn't work.

```
<input type="hidden" id="street" name="street" value="<?php echo $row["street"]; ?>">
```

Those are the fields i want to grab next from each record.  the address fields.  street, city, state, zip.

So for each drop down i want to grab 6 different values and when selecting one of the dropdown items from popup window form, those 6 values should insert into 6 different input boxes of parent page.  what i have so far works fine for 2 values.  just don't know how to do 3 or more.

UPDATE:

what if i don't use a dropdown?  what if i just use divs with id's?  and one of the div items would be a link and when clicking that link, all the div values will be collected of just that row that was clicked?  something like this:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<div style="display: block; clear: both;" id="this_needs_to_be_loop">
<div id="myvendorid" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><?php echo $row["vendorid"]; ?></div>
<div id="myvendorname" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="#" id="link"><?php echo $row["vendorname"]; ?></a></div>
<div id="mystreet" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><?php echo $row["street"]; ?></div>
<div id="mycity" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></div>
<div id="mystate" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><?php echo $row["state"]; ?></div>
<div id="myzip" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><?php echo $row["zip"]; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

my json script looks like this.  doesn't look right.

```
<script>var myDataBase = {"1":{"0":"1","vendorid":"1","1":"34534","vendor_no":"34534","2":"hi","vendorname":"hi","3":"3434534534","phone":"3434534534","4":"sdfsdfs@sdfsdfsd.com","email":"sdfsdfs@sdfsdfsd.com","5":null,"website":null,"6":null,"glacct":null,"7":null,"category":null,"8":"sdfsdfsdf","street":"sdfsdfsdf","9":"sdfsdfsd","city":"sdfsdfsd","10":"sdfsdf","state":"sdfsdf","11":null,"pobox":null,"12":null,"postalcode":null,"13":null,"country":null,"14":null,"description":null},"2":{"0":"2","vendorid":"2","1":"5334534","vendor_no":"5334534","2":"sfsdfsfsd","vendorname":"sfsdfsfsd","3":"78654653","phone":"78654653","4":"ggh@sdsg.com","email":"ggh@sdsg.com","5":null,"website":null,"6":null,"glacct":null,"7":null,"category":null,"8":"sfsdfsdfsdf","street":"sfsdfsdfsdf","9":"sdfsdfsdsdf","city":"sdfsdfsdsdf","10":"sdfsdfsdfsd","state":"sdfsdfsdfsd","11":null,"pobox":null,"12":null,"postalcode":null,"13":null,"country":null,"14":null,"description":null},"4":{"0":"4","vendorid":"4","1":"345342","vendor_no":"345342","2":"dgdf","vendorname":"dgdf","3":"dfgdf","phone":"dfgdf","4":"dfgdfgdf","email":"dfgdfgdf","5":null,"website":null,"6":null,"glacct":null,"7":null,"category":null,"8":"sdfsdsd","street":"sdfsdsd","9":"sdfsfsd","city":"sdfsfsd","10":"sdfsdf","state":"sdfsdf","11":null,"pobox":null,"12":null,"postalcode":null,"13":null,"country":null,"14":null,"description":null},"5":{"0":"5","vendorid":"5","1":"978765345546","vendor_no":"978765345546","2":"jfgsdfjghdfger","vendorname":"jfgsdfjghdfger","3":"54686576456","phone":"54686576456","4":"sdfjhr@dfghjkl.com","email":"sdfjhr@dfghjkl.com","5":null,"website":null,"6":null,"glacct":null,"7":null,"category":null,"8":"gdfgdf","street":"gdfgdf","9":"dfgdfgdf","city":"dfgdfgdf","10":"dfgdfgdf","state":"dfgdfgdf","11":null,"pobox":null,"12":null,"postalcode":null,"13":null,"country":null,"14":null,"description":null}};</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your request. You already have *only* two values for each combo box option. The text of the selected option, and its value. So you can only send those two values back to the parent. Where would the other four values come from?

Comment: from same database record but other fields.  what about if i don't try to make it a drop down, but instead i display all the fields i want and make one of the fields a link?  then when clicking that link the javascript will take all the values from just that row where the link was clicked?

Comment: i will update my question with example of what i mean.

Comment: I have added a fiddle. This ought to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown popup window must perforce contain all the values. You can do this in Javascript.

You will have a loop in PHP that fetches a tuple:

```
{ vendorid, vendorname, street, address, ... }
```

You now use this tuple to create a dropdown:

```
<option value="{$vendorid}">{$vendorname}</option>
```

To do what you want, you need to *also* save the same data in a different structure:

```
<?php
// This is OUTSIDE the cycle that creates the options
$database = array();   

     // This is inside the cycle that creates the options

     $option = "<option value=\"{$data['vendorid']}\">{$data['vendorname']}</option>";

     $database[$data['vendorid']] = $data;

// Now the cycle has ended. We print the data in Javascript.

print "<script>";
print "var myDataBase = ";
print json_encode($database);
print ";\n";
print "</script>";
```

The above defines a Javascript array which is much like a PHP one, with the fields having the same names as in PHP thanks to `json_encode`.

Now in the Javascript you get the vendor Id as before:

```
var vendor_id = vendor_nameSelect.options[vendor_nameSelect.selectedIndex].value;
```

This `vendor_id` is a key inside what is now a Javascript variable, `myDataBase`. So you can do:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("streetfieldid").value
    = myDatabase[vendor_id]["street"];

window.opener.document.getElementById("addressfieldid").value
    = myDatabase[vendor_id]["address"];


...and so on.
```

You can see the concept in action (except for PHP of course) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ukA9k/). I have only used three fields and they are all in the same page, but the modifications are trivial. To generate `myDataBase` you use the above PHP code.

Comment: i'm not following.  by the way here is where i got the child popup dropdown that inserts value into parent. aspsnippets.com/demos/662/

Comment: i modified mine so the value and text go into 2 different fields of parent page.  one showing and one hidden.  for the 3rd through 6th fields they will be showing, but i don't know how to do the loop and javascript in popup window.

Comment: As I said, I had terribly misunderstood your request. The above is a different solution.

Comment: thanks for the html and javascript example, but i don't know how to do the php part.  i never heard of tuple or how to create it.